# Getting a PKCS#7 signature with CryptSignHash

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, cryptoapi

[CryptSignMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can to produce a PKCS#7 signature by passing the appropriate encoding type in the PCRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA parameter. But I cannot seem to find a way to do the same thing with the [CryptSignHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380280(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Is there a way to create a PKCS#7 signature using the CryptSignHash API or is there any other function which can be called to convert the output of CryptSignHash to PKCS#7?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot convert the output of `CryptSignHash` to the output of `CryptSignMessage`.

`CryptSignMessage` creates the CMS *container format* for creating a digital signature. This is not just a digital signature as in the cryptographic definition of a signature. The message is first hashed, then that hashes + possible other information is hashed and signed. So the resulting signature is not a direct signature over the data.

With `CryptSignHash` you do directly sign the given hash. And that hash is performed directly over the data. Because the hash is one way, you cannot reconstruct the data, so you cannot perform the scheme required by `CryptSignMessage`.

In short, although the names of these methods seem similar, both function perform crypto at a different level. One is just the cryptographic primitive, the other is an application level protocol.

Comment: PS that's a pretty nice profile for somebody still posting under such an anonymous name, hope I can be of some help